# mount with cifs and sec=krb5 fails with "Required key not available"

Tags: mount, pam, active-directory, kerberos, autofs

#### The problem

First time posting here, and also not the most super experienced ubuntu user, so I hope that I can describe my problem well enough.

I am trying to mount a windows fileshare to our ubuntu system with multiuser access, so that we can give different users access to different folders on the fileshare.

The idea is to eventually automate the mount with autofs or pam_mount, but currently I am just trying to mount manually for testing purposes.

The ubuntu machine is domain joined to our AD and I can log in with my personal user account. The problem arises when I am trying to mount the fileshare from my personal user account. It seems that `mount -t cifs` is looking for kerberos tickets owned by the root user but not for kerberos tickets owned by my personal account.

I have tested this with both ubuntu 20.04 and 24.04.

#### Testing with manual mount not working

When I run the following mount command (I have tested with both vers=2.0 and vers=3.0):

```
ahb@<domain-name>@htcondor-submit:~$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o sec=krb5,vers=2.0,cruid=$USER,user=$USER,gid=$GID //fileport/Cluster-test /mnt2/fileport/Cluster-test
```

I get the error (also I don't know why mount is called twice but I don't think that affects anything):

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.1.5.45,unc=\\fileport\Cluster-test,sec=krb5,vers=2.0,cruid=1331401727,user=ahb@ad.<domain>.com,pass=********
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.1.5.45,unc=\\fileport\Cluster-test,sec=krb5,vers=2.0,cruid=1331401727,user=ahb@ad.<domain>.com,pass=********
mount error(126): Required key not available
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

However, I clearly have a kerberos ticket in the ticket cache:

```
ahb@ad.<domain>.com@htcondor-submit:~$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1331401727_WCwLhQ
Default principal: AHB@AD.<domain>.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
12/15/23 09:53:43  12/15/23 19:53:43  krbtgt/AD.<domain>.COM@AD.<domain>.COM
        renew until 12/16/23 09:53:43
```

#### It works with a kerberos ticket in the root cache

I can get the mount to work if I create a kerberos ticket from the root user. The following is what I do.

I log in as root and create a kerberos ticket for my personal user like so:

```
root@htcondor-submit:/# kinit AHB@AD.<domain>.COM
Password for AHB@AD.<domain>.COM: 

root@htcondor-submit:/# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: AHB@AD.<domain>.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
12/15/23 10:06:02  12/15/23 20:06:02  krbtgt/AD.<domain>.COM@AD.<domain>.COM
        renew until 12/16/23 10:05:57
```

After this I log back in as my personal account. Now, if I run the same mount command as above it still fails due to the cruid=$USER option. If I remove that option, it is looking for a kerberos ticket owner by the root and it works. This is the command:

```
ahb@ad.<domain>.com@htcondor-submit:~$ sudo mount -v -t cifs -o sec=krb5,vers=3.0,user=$USER,gid=$GID //fileport/Cluster-test /mnt2/fileport/Cluster-test
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.1.5.45,unc=\\fileport\Cluster-test,sec=krb5,vers=3.0,user=ahb@ad.<domain>.com,pass=********
```

Now I can see my file in the drive:

```
ahb@ad.<domain>.com@htcondor-submit:~$ ls /mnt2/fileport/Cluster-test/          
AHB-TEST
```

#### How do I get mount -t cifs to look for a kerberos ticket owned by the user and not root?

I don't think it is a viable option to create krb5 tickets with the root user as we will have many people logging into this system with their personal user accounts. The krb5 tickets are currently created every time someone logs in with their personal account but they are stored in their personal ticket cache.

To resolve this, I think I need to figure out how to properly configure kerberos and/or mount.cifs to look for a kerberos ticket owned by the user.
I have already tested autofs and pam_mount and both seems to have similar issues, that the mount works but only with the root owned krb5 tickets.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance,

Alexander

Comment: iirc together with `cruid` you need the `-K` option for "per-user keytab" to point to a specific keytab file

Comment: Thanks, @Rinzwind. I'm not too familiar with keytab files and how it works. Also, I can't see the `-K` option in the manpage for mount. 
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/mount.8.html

Could you perhaps elaborate a little?

Comment: It is part of Kerberos configuration not part of mount. But its been ages since we last use that so I am not sure.  does this help: https://linux.die.net/man/1/kinit